# Content Porter skips Razor TBBs when importing

Tags: razormediator, content-porter-2013, 2013-sp1

I can export Razor TBBs just fine from my Tridion 2013 SP1 system (using Content Porter 2013 SP1), however whenever I import, it skips them - they are not counted in the successful or failed items in the summary at the end, or listed in the list of processed items, and there are no errors in the logs either the Content Porter log, or the Tridion Event log on the server. I have tried importing on a separate environment, but also importing on the environment that I originally exported. The behavior is the same on both, leading me to believe that this is a Content Porter, rather than an environment/installation issue.

UPDATE: Further testing shows that this actually only happens with a Helpers TBB which is configured in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file as automatically imported for all TBBs. If I manually create this in the target environment, subsequent TBBs (which have a dependency on this) are imported OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the (optional) management of dependencies that is a feature of the Razor Mediator. If (in `Tridion.ContentManager.config`) you set the **includeConfigWhereUsed** attribute to **true** in the Razor configuration section then every Razor TBB you subsequently create or edit will have a dependency on Razor TBB(s) set to globally import in the **imports** element. The problem is that this includes those imported TBBs themselves, so a circular dependency is created.

This only becomes a problem if you try to delete the imported TBB (not possible as it uses itself), or if you try to export and import it with Content Porter (presumably Content Porter detects the circular dependency and skips the item).

The workaround is either to manually create the imported TBB, or to change **includeConfigWhereUsed** to **false**.

There is an [issue open](https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/issues/detail?id=12) in the Razor Mediator project to fix this.